# If statement gives me undefined result

Tags: javascript

I ve built a form that displays results according what the users select. I am trying to put an if statement together which will output datasheet 1 on choosing the specific values.
I want when somebody choose the 525 and the 134  and the 290 to give me datasheet 1 else give me the datasheet 3. Here is my code:

```
<form name="test" id="test"">
    <label for="select1">Height in (mm)</label>
        <select name="division-select" id="height">
        <option label="Please Select"></option>
            <option value="525">525 or less</option>
            <option value="645">645 or less</option>
            <option value="1265">up to 1265</option>
            <option value="1270">more than 1265</option>
        </select>
        <label for="select1">Width in (mm)</label>
        <select name="division-select" id="width">
        <option label="Please Select"></option>
            <option value="134w">134 or less</option>
            <option value="190w">190 or less </option>
            <option value="290w">290 or less</option>
            <option value="328w">328 or less</option>
            <option value="420w">420 or more</option>
        </select>
        <Br>
        <br>
        <label for="select1">Depth in (mm)</label>
        <select name="division-select" id="depth">
        <option label="Please Select"></option>
            <option value="134d">134 or less</option>
            <option value="190d">190 or less </option>
            <option value="290d">290 or less</option>
            <option value="328d">328 or less</option>
            <option value="420d">420 or more</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <h2>Or select by load</h2>
        <label for="select1">Load in (kN)</label>
        <select name="division-select" id="load">
            <option label="Please Select"></option>
            <option value="2-5">2.5 or less</option>
            <option value="5">5 or less </option>
            <option value="10">10 or less</option>
            <option value="25">25 or less</option>
            <option value="50">50 or more</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <p><input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Find your Datasheet" /><input type="button" onclick="formReset()" value="Reset form"></p>

</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    var depth = document.getElementById('depth').value;
    var load = document.getElementById('load').value;
    if (document.getElementById("height").value == "") {
        var heightmsg = "Please select your sample's height.";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = heightmsg;
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("width").value == "") {
        var widthmsg = "Please select your sample's width.";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = widthmsg;
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("depth").value == "") {
        var depthmsg = "Please select your sample's depth.";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = depthmsg;
        return false;
    }
    if (height === "525" && width === "134" && depth === "290") {
        if (height === "525" && width === "290" && depth === "134") {
            var str = '<a href="#">Download your Datasheet 1</a>';
        } else {
            var str = '<a href="#">Download your Datasheet 3</a>';
        }
    } else if (height == 1270) {
        var str = "This configuration is beyond the standard range of top-load testers. Please contact Mecmesin Sales to discuss ways to meet your requirements.";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}

function formReset() {
    document.getElementById("test").reset();
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I select height 525 and width 134 and height 290 gives me undefined result :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your width and depth values end in w and d (e.g. `<option value="190d">`) but you're not checking for that in your if conditions (`if (height === "525" && width === "134" && depth === "290")`). Take the w and d out of the values like this:

```
<select name="division-select" id="width">
    <option label="Please Select"></option>
    <option value="134">134 or less</option>
    <option value="190">190 or less</option>
    <option value="290">290 or less</option>
    <option value="328">328 or less</option>
    <option value="420">420 or more</option>
</select>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GPQqp/)**

Side note: you have a condition which appears to never be able to be true:

```
if (height === "525" && width === "134" && depth === "290") {
    if (height === "525" && width === "290" && depth === "134")...
```

Comment: So how can I make it true? I tested that and its kind of working but instead of giving me datasheet 1 its giving me the datasheet 3. Why is it doing that?

Comment: See the note I just added.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (height === "525" && width === "134" && depth === "290") {
    if (height === "525" && width === "290" && depth === "134") {
```

makes no sense. If the first condition is true, the second never can be. I guess you want

```
if (height === "525" && width === "290" && depth === "134")
    var str = '<a href="#">Download your Datasheet 1</a>';
else if (height === "525" && width === "134" && depth === "290")
    var str = '<a href="#">Download your Datasheet 3</a>';
else if (height == 1270)
    var str = "This configuration is beyond the standard range of top-load testers. Please contact Mecmesin Sales to discuss ways to meet your requirements.";
```

Also notice that the values of your `<option>` tags are suffixed with `w` and `d`, so they won't equal the suffix-less numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. It was correct but unfortunately I cant select you both :P

Answer (score 0):

you are using too many if statements, if you want to specify a seperate link for every option from the three select inputs (width, height, depth) you'll end up with 4x5x5 = 100 if statements. the easiest way around this is to create a mysql databases with all the values and correspondents links, alternatively you can use XML or JSON array.

for the empty select input validation you can use:

```
var height = document.getElementById('height'),
    width = document.getElementById('width'),
    depth = document.getElementById('depth'),
    load = document.getElementById('load'),
    result = document.getElementById('result'),
    arr = [height, width, depth],
    error = "Please select your sample's ";

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var t = arr[i].id;
    if (arr[i].value == "") result.innerHTML = error + t;
    return false;
}
```

for JSON example see the Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CCU97/) on jsfiddle.